# ScrollView в сочетании с RelativeLayout добавляет пустое место

Tags: android

`ScrollView(layout_height="match_parent")` в сочетании с `RelativeLayout(layout_height="wrap_content")` добавляет пустое место в `RelativeLayout`.

Cкриншот с устройства с включенным режимом просмотра границ макета:

[image]

На фотографии четко видно границы `RelativeLayout`.

[image]

Структура компонентов:

[image]

При этом если убрать `ScrollView` то размер `RelativeLayout` будет правильный.

`LinearLayout` ведет себя так-же.

Пример кода:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#37363B"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/phone_top"
        android:id="@+id/phone_top_bask" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_top_bask"
        android:layout_above="@+id/process_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:overScrollMode="never">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:background="@drawable/unis_bg_new"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <Тут дочерние компоненты>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/bottom"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#F4F5F6"
        android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/process_bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `restore_data_manual_2`, `restore_data_manual_3` - у них `visibility = invisible`?

Comment: @metalurgus `visibility=gone` и из класса, когда нужно, меняется на `visibility=visible`

Comment: Тогда вроде все правильно... Вы пробовали на дивайсе, или на эмеляторе запускать? Рендеринг превью не всегда точный.

Comment: @metalurgus скриншот с устройства с включенным режимом просмотра границ макета: [скриншот](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nCv9b4K7Vhw/VjNpfetm4GI/AAAAAAAAABc/hvnZ15e0Sh4/s512/2015-10-30.jpg)

Comment: нету, вставьте в вопрос

Comment: @metalurgus добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, все именно так, как вы и попросили: `ScollView` располагается между двумя `TextView`, и занимает все место между ними - `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"`. 
`RelativeLayout` внутри `ScrollView` заканчивается ровно там, где заканчивается последний View, вложенный в него, как и видно на скриншоте. Если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите, то вам нужно у `ScrollView` выставить `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, привязать нижний `TextView` к `ScrollView`, и отвязать нижний `TextView` от низа парента `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: Нельзя привязать элемент к ScrollView. К тому же это никак не повлияет на высоту дочернего `RelativeLayout `. Я попробовал переделать корневой `RelativeLayout ` на `LinearLayout ` и ошибка сохраняется.

Comment: @VladShipugin, можно привязать. Я только что попробовал. И на высоту `RelativeLayout ` ничего не повлияет, потому что она правильная у вас.  Вам надо повлиять на высоту `ScrollView`. Чтобы вам было лучше видно, задайте для `ScrollView`, `RelativeLayout `разный цвет фона, и посмотрите, что где начинается и заканчивается.

Comment: Я поменял цвета: `ScrollView` - красный, `RelativeLayout` - зеленый. http://joxi.ru/bmoW10bUp3apmy  и, по моему фон который был у `RelativeLayout` влиял на его размер.

Comment: Я поменял удрал фон с `RelativeLayou` и повесил его на `ScrollView`. Проблема устранена.